# Calling a function inside another function of the same class

Tags: c++

So basically this is the code (the part that matters):

```
class leaders {
public:
    leaders(int maze_num, int time_taken);
    static bool myfunc(string& i, string& j);
    void leaders_func(int maze_num, int time_taken);
};

bool leaders::myfunc(string& i, string& j) {
    string stri1 = i.substr(16, 5);
    string stri2 = j.substr(16, 5);
    return (stoi(stri1) < stoi(stri2));
}

void leaders::leaders_func(int maze_num, int time_taken) {
    vector<string> v1;
    //vector contains strings with this format -> "John - 329","Jack - 348", etc.
    sort(v1.begin() + 2, v1.end(), myfunc); 
}

int main() {
    leaders l1(15, 225);
}
```

But some error occurs when I try to run the program. I ran it without a class before, just 2 functions normally and there was no problem but when I put it into a class, it started to create some errors... can anyone point out the problem (if there is one)?

The errors are:

> 1: 'leaders::myfunc': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member
>
> 2: 'sort': no matching overloaded function found
>
> 3: 'void std::sort(const _RanIt,const _RanIt)': expects 2 arguments - 3 provided

***Edit 4** - Changed the whole code part (now as shown above) but now there's another error:

> "public: __thiscall leaders::leaders(int,int)" (??0leaders@@QAE@HH@Z) referenced in function _main

**Question** - I was also thinking maybe in the sort thing that I needed to put leaders::myfunc instead of just myfunc but I'm not gonna change it unless someone says it's the right thing to do.

Comment: Where's the parameter list for the implementation of `leaders_func`.  And where's the scope resolution operator?  Is this how your C++ book describes implementing member functions?

Comment: Another thing that you have brackets after the class name.

Comment: Hint: `bool leaders::myfunc(...)`.

Comment: Please, when talking about errors *include the exact error text*. An infinite number of things can go wrong when compiling. Help us narrow it down a little.

Comment: @tadman Here are the errors shown:
1: 'leaders::myfunc': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member
2: 'sort': no matching overloaded function found
3: 'void std::sort(const _RanIt,const _RanIt)': expects 2 arguments - 3 provided

Comment: That's good to know, but it helps if you put that in the body of your question with an edit.

Comment: One problem here is that `myfunc` is a member function, but `std::sort` wants a regular (non-member) function. Consider using a `static` function for `myfunc`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

class leaders {
public:
    static bool myfunc(std::string i, std::string j);
    void leaders_func(int maze_num, int time_taken);
};

bool leaders::myfunc(std::string i, std::string j) {
    std::string stri1 = i.substr(16, 5);
    std::string stri2 = j.substr(16, 5);
    return (std::stoi(stri1) < std::stoi(stri2));
}

void leaders::leaders_func(int maze_num, int time_taken) {
    std::vector<std::string> v1;
    //vector contains strings with this format -> "John - 329","Jack - 348", etc.
    //std::sort(v1.begin() + 2, v1.end());
    std::sort(v1.begin() + 2, v1.end(), myfunc);
}
```

if you want to define a function (whose declaration is in a class) outside of a class, you  need to fully qualify the name.

You also need to declare `myfunc()` `static`, as `std::sort` wants a non-member function as it's parameter.

Comment: I am trying to find out what the difference between your code and mine is... maybe you haven't seen the edits? Thanks anyways!

Comment: @GuilhermeMoreira Sorry, my clipboard goes crazy, I pasted the wrong code